# ¿Cómo se puede elegir el "candidato" en una tabla llamada "voto"?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, interfaz-gráfica, backend

Estoy diseñando una base de datos y quiero saber si mi tabla "voto" debe tener la opción de marcar al candidato, o eso se hace en la interfaz de usuario.
Mi tabla "voto" muestra las foreign key de las entidades "candidato principal" y "candidato secundario" y eso me da entender que ya el voto se ha rellenado por si solo, pero no por medio del "votante", así que no se si eso sea correcto.

Gracias por sus respuestas de antemano.

[image: Tabla de Voto]

Comment: No se si se habra rellenado por si solo durante la creación de las foreign keys o a traves de tu código donde permites el voto, pues no lo pones y no sabemos lo que hacen los votantes al votar en tu sitio web. Plantéate agregar las consultas INSERT correspondientes así como el formulario que las rellena que los votantes estan usando para votar en la pregunta. Puedes pulsar sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta para modificarla y agregar esa información.

Comment: @masterguru también puede añadir un campo boolean llamado convocatoria o votaciones a los candidatos para saber si participa o no :-)

Comment: @JavierG.Raya pues no se, ni idea si es eso lo que quiere, su pregunta me queda un poco ambigua a mi entender y espero clarificaciones para poder ayudar mejor... mientras tanto prefiero no especular demasiado a menos que se me encienda la bombilla y le entienda mejor :-)

Comment: estoy contigo @masterguru debería añadir mas detalles..... :-)

Comment: Copiar y pegar (texto) es la forma correcta de compartir el código. [es.so] es un sitio de código en formato texto. Para postear imágenes tienes las redes antisociales, como Instagram, Twitter, Facebook, etc. Aquí debes compartir el código como texto, ya que muchos no pueden ver las imágenes, no se puede copiar y pegar el código que hay en ellas sin tener que transcribirlo, y tampoco se puede indexar el texto de una imagen. Además, el proceso de capturar la imagen salvarla, subirla y por fin anexarla a la pregunta siempre será más largo que un simple *copy / paste*. ¿No crees?